# Prevent Help Make Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Better message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When starting Microsoft SQL Server, I get this message:
**Help Make Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Better**

How can I prevent this from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find an icon in the control tray for this, bottom right. You can select that and uncheck the participation box or choose No, I dont recall exactly the wording. Message should stop appearing then.